# Is it possible to insert a custom attribute to a <message/> in aioxmpp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmpp, python-asyncio

I'm trying to add custom attributes to a Message, but I'm not sure I've understood xso.

```
class Message(aioxmpp.Message):
    performative = aioxmpp.xso.Attr(tag="performative", 
                                    type_=aioxmpp.xso.String(),
                                    default="query")
```

This code is not resulting on receiving a message with a custom attribute.
I can't even print the message and see the new attribute. Could you please guide me to the solution?

Comment: You usually want to insert custom extension elements, not custom attributes.

Comment: aioxmpp creator helped me to find the solution. It's in this gist: https://gist.github.com/javipalanca/d17222430cee165892ef53af8a469c4a

Comment: Please go ahead and answer your on question then :)